# Как отключить на сайте системный скейлинг (маштаб и разметка винды)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Некоторые пользователи заходят на сайт с ноутбуков, где в системе выставлена эта настройка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно едет вёрстка на сайте. Вижу что большие компании как-то с этим борются, подскажите как?:) Как-то двигают браузерный зум?
Пробовал играться с тегом "meta", вроде не оно.

Comment: Используют `rem`, `em` и `@media` :)

Comment: ну так все могут)

Comment: Вдруг будет полезна [эта статья](https://silvawebdesigns.com/how-to-fix-windows-scaling-issues-above-100-for-your-website/)

Comment: ну то же самое по сути)